# Editable table written in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabular

I'm looking for an editable table that can be used on desktops and mobile devices, I've found a few editable tables ([one from Kendo which was very nice](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html)) but they run incredibly laggy on phones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a combination of jquery datatables http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html + jeditable http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Perhaps you can give it a try. Hope this works for u!

Comment: was just looking at datatables, I'll go with that one, it's simple but runs really well on mobile devices and is editable.